# Printing output based of two list

Tags: python

I have a list containing string elements:

```
movielst = ['A WALK,DRAGONBALL', 'JAMES BOND,MISSION']
```

and another list that contains integer values:

```
userlst = [[1,20],[6,7]]
```

I'm planning to print the output based off both list where the first element in movielst corresponds to the first list in userlst and so on.

Output to get:

```
Movies: A WALK,DRAGONBALL
Users: 1,20

Movies: JAMES BOND,MISSION
Users: 6,7
```

I wrote

```
for j in range(len(userlst)-1):
    for i in movielst:
        print("Movies: " + str(i))
        print("Users: " + str(userlst[j]))
```

But I'm getting:

```
Movies: A WALK,DRAGONBALL
Users: 1,20

Movies: JAMES BOND,MISSION
Users: 1,20               #should be 6,7
```

How do i print the output based off both lists in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`

**Ex:**

```
movielst = ['A WALK,DRAGONBALL', 'JAMES BOND,MISSION']
userlst = [[1,20],[6,7]]
for i in zip(movielst, userlst):
    print("Movies: {}".format(i[0]))
    print("Users: {}".format(", ".join(map(str, i[1]))))
```

**Output:**

```
Movies: A WALK,DRAGONBALL
Users: 1, 20
Movies: JAMES BOND,MISSION
Users: 6, 7
```

**Note:**

1. I have used `map` to convert int to string for userlst
2. `join` to concat the element in userlst to your required format.

Answer (score 1):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), and [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) with a comprehension:

```
>>> print '\n'.join("Movies: {}\nUsers: {}".format(x,y) for x,y in zip(movielst,userlst))
Movies: A WALK,DRAGONBALL
Users: [1, 20]
Movies: JAMES BOND,MISSION
Users: [6, 7]
```

Or, as stated in comments and if you want double spaced:

```
>>> print '\n\n'.join("Movies: {}\nUsers: {}".format(*z) for z in zip(movielst,userlst))
Movies: A WALK,DRAGONBALL
Users: [1, 20]

Movies: JAMES BOND,MISSION
Users: [6, 7]
```

Comment: Nice solution. We could again simplify this without unpacking `x` and `y`.  ie, `print('\n'.join("Movies: {}\nUsers: {}".format(*args) for args in zip(movielst,userlst)))`.  But your answer is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you know both lists are the same length:

```
for i in range(len(movielst)):
    print("Movies: {}".format(str(movielst[i]))
    print("Users: {}".format(str(userlst[i])))
    print(' ')
```

This way you loop over both loops and print the same index of both lists in the same loop.

The .format works as following:

```
print('text {} text {}'.format(<first thing>, <second thing>))
```

outputs:

```
text <first thing> text <second thing>
```

Answer (score 0):

The j in the first loop will not increase until 'i' traverse through every element, so j will print 1.20 both times. For traversing through both lists at the same time you can use one for loop.

```
for j in range(len(userlst)):
    print("Movies: " + str(movielst[j]))
    print("Users: " + str(userlst[j]))
```

The output will be :

```
Movies: A WALK,DRAGONBALL  
Users: [1, 20]  
Movies: JAMES BOND,MISSION
Users: [6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
movielst = ['A WALK,DRAGONBALL', 'JAMES BOND,MISSION']

userlst = [[1,20],[6,7]]

for i in zip(movielst,userlst):
    print("Movies : {}".format(i[0]))
    print("Users : {} {}".format(*i[1]))
```

output:

```
Movies : A WALK,DRAGONBALL
Users : 1 20
Movies : JAMES BOND,MISSION
Users : 6 7
```